# mysql array to string conversion

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm trying to query with a php list, I'm not even sure if it is possible but hopefully you can give some advice/assistance on the matter.
 
I get a zip list from another function that contains a lot of zip codes, and I want to use that list to narrow down a search.

> Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\wamp\www

This is where I get the array to string error
`. JOIN zip_list zl ON r.zip_code IN ('$zip_list') "`

I know it works perfectly with replacing $zip_list with ('2150','2165') for example but the list will be rather long so I can't just put $zip_list[$i].

I've tried some conversion with $trimZip and $test but it always yields the same error.

```
for($i=0; $i<count($zip_list); $i++){
    array_push($trimZip, "'".$zip_list[$i]."',");
    $i = $i+1;
}
for($i = 0; $i<count($trimZip); $i++){
    $test[$i] = $trimZip[$i];
}
```

Is there a good way to do this or am I even looking at it the right way ? 
Better/easier angles are welcome too!

Comment: So `$zip_list` is an array ? And you want the values of the array to be concatenated as a string ?

Comment: You can use `implode()`. Like `$zip_list = implode(',', $zip_list);` ?

Comment: @frz3993 Yes it is an array at the moment. I got it working with putting a for loop around the whole query but that will lead to quite a few queries which is unfortunate. But it will do for now

I'll give implode a go and see how that works out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
$sql_string = implode(', ', $zip_list);
```

should do it.

Sample:

```
$zip_list = array(1, 2);
$sql_string = implode(', ', $zip_list);
echo $sql_string;
```

Output:

```
1, 2
```

Demo: https://eval.in/483839

This presumes you validated the data in `$zip_list` when assigning it. Variables being used directly in SQL isn't good practice. You should really look into parameterized queries.

I'd do:

```
$zip_list = array(1, 2);
foreach($zip_list as $param) {
     $placeholders[] = '?';
}
$sql_string = implode(', ', $placeholders);
echo $sql_string;
```

Then use `$sql_string` in the prepare and `$zip_list` in the execute.

Dependent on your driver:

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php
http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Seems to be working, thank you. I will have a look at it

Comment: If it resolves your issue please remember to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

> $sql_string = implode(', ', $zip_list);

Implode did the trick, thanks for the help